# $_GET doesn't work in my program and no lines beneath it are executed

Tags: php, html, get

I am trying to add a function to my website where it will add filters to a SQL select statement by allowing the user to enter text in some text boxes and clicking the filter button.

I haven't gotten as far as that because I'm having issues with the $_GET function.

The idea is that if the query parameters are set, it will use them in the sql statement and if not, it will just return all the rows.

Below is the displayListings function which is called every time the page is loaded.
Although I'm showing the whole function, I havent implemented most of it because nothing works past the line where I use $_GET.

```
    <?php
    function displayListings() {
        global $dbConnection;

        //checks if the query parameters exist
        if (isset($_GET['title'])) {
            echo 'got here... :F';//for debugging
            var_dump($_GET['title']);//for debugging
            $title_filter = $_GET('title');// THIS IS THE LINE THAT THE SCRIPT STOPS AT
            var_dump($title_filter);//for debugging
        }
        //checks if the query parameters exist
        if (isset($_GET['artist'])) {
            $artist_filter = $_GET('artist');
            echo $artist_filter."/n";
        }
        //checks if the query parameters exist
        if (isset($_GET['release'])) {
            $release_filter = $_GET('release');
            echo $release_filter."/n";
        }

        echo 'here!';

        // connect to the database
        if (!connectToDb('musiconline')) {
            $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "Sorry, we could not connect to the database.";
            header('location:listItem.php');
            exit();
        }

        // after this point we have an open DB connection
        // gets the current highest ID so we know what the next should be.
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT listingid, recordtitle, artist FROM vinyl";
        $result = $dbConnection->query($sqlQuery);
        if (!$result) {
            $_SESSION['errorMsg'] = "There was a problem with the database: " . $dbConnection->error;
            closeConnection();
            header('location:listItem.php');
            exit();
        }
        
        //gets the results and puts them in a rows array
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        //iterates through each row of the results (each vinyl)
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $listingID = $row['listingid'];
            $recordTitle = $row['recordtitle'];
            $artist = $row['artist'];

            echo '  
                    <div class="listing">
                        <table class="tableception">
                            <tr><td><img src="uploads/vinyl'.$listingID.'.png" alt="img1" ></td><td>
                                <table class="listing-table">
                                    <tr><td>Album title:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$recordTitle.'</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Artist name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>'.$artist.'</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            ' . "\n";
        }//END OF FOREACH

        /* free result set */
        $result->close();

        /* close connection */
        closeConnection();
    }
?>
```

When I debug the page in my IDE, everything works fine, probably because there are no query parameters in the URL.

The page stops loading after the $_GET line, as seen below.[shows screenshot of browser when query parameters exist in URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGk03.png).

I just cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$_GET` is not a function, it's a superglobal (associative array), using the function syntax with parenthesis won't work.

Comment: Jesus christ it was so simple... Thanks a lot. I was using curly brackets instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I used curly brackets instead of square brackets in the line.

I had  `$title_filter = $_GET('title');`
instead of `$title_filter = $_GET['title'];`

Thanks @AymDev for pointing this out to me!